# Compare two separate dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm new to Python and looking to figure out how to code this properly. I have two lists of dictionaries and I'm trying to find if the student ID exists in a string that can contain the student ID and other information. My badly formed approach:

```
confirmed_students = [{'div_school_id': 'as-dh23d7ashdh'}, {'div_school_id': 'asdas-3sdfasd'}, {'div_school_id': 'i4-d9asjcg'}] 

students = [{'student_id': 'dh23d7ashdh','name': 'First Last','student_grade': '4'}, {'student_id':'3sdfasd', 'name':...}] 

bad_list = []
for student in students:
    if student['student_id'] not in confirmed_students:
        bad_list.append({"id": student['student_id'], "name": student['name'], "grade": student['student_grade']})
```

What would be the proper way to do this? Should I iterate through the list of dicts `confirmed_students` in the same loop? I only need to know if the `student_id` from the list of dicts called `students` exists at all in the list of dicts called `confirmed_students` and add the relevant info.

Comment: Confirmed_students looks like: 
[{'div_school_id': 'as-dh23d7ashdh'}, {div_school_id': 'asdas-3sdfasd'}, {div_school_id': 'i4-d9asjcg'}]

While students looks like:
[{'student_id': 'dh23d7ashdh','name': 'First Last','student_grade': '4'}, {'student_id':'3sdfasd', 'name':...}]

Comment: @eod Please add the `confirmed_students` format in the question itself.

Comment: doesn't look like there is a matching key between the dicts?

Comment: Might be easier making the list of dictionaries containing the same `div_school_id` a list of just ids first.

Comment: There is no matching key. I can change the list of `div_school_id` to just a plain list also I believe.

Comment: if your confirmed_students list was formatted like `confirmed_students = ['as-dh23d7ashdh', 'asdas-3sdfasd', 'i4-d9asjcg']` your current code would work. Otherwise you need to iterate the second dictionary as Will suggested.

Comment: Thanks! I updated `confirmed_students` to be a list like you suggested, however len(bad_list) and len(confirmed_students) is still the same number.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think I've gotten this figured out by just keeping the student IDs both in a plain list and comparing like `[x for x in students if all(x not in y for y in confirmed_students)]`, then appending student ID, name, grade etc to a separate list of dicts.

Answer (score 1):

A brute force way of getting there (and probably not the most efficient) is to loop over both lists. Check if each element of *students* is in *confirmed_students*.

Firstly, you need a way of knowing if the *student* is in the *confirmed_students* list. There must be a key to match on. Looking at your data it seems as if *confirmed_students* has *div_school_id* that is some kind of composite of the *student_id* and some prefix.

```
# looking at one confirmed student as an example
confirmed_student = confirmed_students[0]
# confirmed_student = {'div_school_id': 'as-dh23d7ashdh'}
# we need to split the id on the '-' and keep the last part
confirmed_student_id = confirmed_student['div_school_id'].split("-")[1]
# gives us confirmed_student_id as 'dh23d7ashdh' which looks right?

# now we loop over your students and see if their id is in confirmed_students
bad_list = []
for student in students:
    for confirmed_student in confirmed_students:
        confirmed_student_id = confirmed_student['div_school_id'].split("-")[1]
        if student["student_id"] == confirmed_student_id:
            bad_list.append({"id": student['student_id'], "name": student['name'], "grade": student.get('student_grade', '')})
            # break from the inner loop and continue the outer loop
            # because we only need the first match
            break
```

Comment: And you need to `break` as soon as you find such a match and add to the `bad_list`.

Comment: yes. just saw that. need to break from the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I copied your suggestion, however the results end up being 0. Is this because `==` is looking for an exact match? I also tried `in` and `not in`, however `bad_list` ends up being the same number of elements as `students`:


print(len(students))
1713
print(len(bad_list))
1713

Comment: I'm going to update this answer based on your edits to the question

Comment: your bad list can be the same length if all your students are confirmed students. You need test data in which the two lists are different, then we can see what goes wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can build the list using list comprehension:

```
bad_list = [{k: student[v] for k, v in zip(('id', 'name', 'grade'), ('student_id', 'name', 'student_grade'))} for student in students if student['student_id'] not in confirmed_students]
```

Sidenote: I suggest you define the students as a dictionary using the student_id as key (assuming it is unique, which it should). It will make it much more easier to perform comparisons like the one you want.

Comment: Thanks! Would this need to be a nested dictionary with the student ID as the key? I tried your suggestion as is but received the error `KeyError: 'i'`.